# Accessing a field from a differen't model's table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that displays a filtered table based on the user that is passed to the page. I also want to display the user's info a the top of the page, but this comes from a different table (from the Account model). Is there a way I can access fields from this table while working in my other controller/views?

Here is my code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Profile";
}

@model IEnumerable<FTv2.Models.Trade>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Active Trades";
    ViewBag.ImgUrl = ViewBag.Name + ".png";
}


<h2>@ViewBag.User's Profile:</h2>
<p>
    // This is where I would like to put the User info.
</p>
<h2>Active Trades:</h2>
<p>

</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.User == ViewBag.User)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @{ViewBag.ImgUrl = @item.Name + ".png";}
        <a href="/Images/@ViewBag.ImgUrl"><img src="/Images/@ViewBag.ImgUrl" HEIGHT="66" WIDTH="50" ></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price) TE
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/ActiveTrades/@item.User">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)</a>
        </td>
        @{if (ViewBag.User == User.Identity.Name){
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
        }}
    </tr>
    }
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that I can think of:

1. Render an action method that returns the user details

   @{

   ```
   Html.RenderAction("UserDetails", new { UserID = ViewBag.UserID});
   ```

   }
2. Create a new model that has the user details plus an IEnumerable of the trades and use this for your view.

Comment: Thanks for your response, would you mind elaborating a little on how I would use renderaction? Let's say I want to pull the entry for the "FID" field for a certain user, how would I do this?

Comment: You'd create another action on your controller which expects the userID parameter (or whatever you call it). This action builds up a model of the user details and passes it to a view for rendering. Think of it as a view within a view.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you wanna

- make page model that will contain the User Info and `IEnumerable<...>`.
- or pass User info into ViewBag
- or call `@Html.RenderAction()`

I think that you need to keep in mind the chance of reuse of the view model class. If you see no way to reuse the model then use ViewBag to pass the info into a View. In the Controller's Action set the property ViewBag.UserInfo = userInfo; and in the view call: `code`@Html.Partial("_UserInfo", (UserInfo)ViewBag.UserInfo)`code`. 
But more practical way is to call @Html.Action(): 
1. Make action UserController.UserInfo(int id). 
2. Call from your view @Html.Action("UserInfo", "User", new {Id = ViewBag.UserId}); 
3. create partial view for the UserController.UserInfo action.

Comment: Sorry I am pretty new to this and having a lot of trouble understanding exactly what I need to do. Would you mind explaining what I need to do a little more precisely? 

Do I need to make an entirely new model.cs page, or if not which page should I put the new model in?